# Organization Chart js with custom layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, charts

I need to make Organization Chart like this with PHP Laravel & Jquery [image: counting_organization_chart]
I've tried looking for references, like GoJS, OrgChart etc but haven't found a suitable one. do you have a reference i can use? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete stand-alone sample.  You just need to get the data to the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minimal GoJS Sample</title>
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2022 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:600px"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
  <script id="code">
const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

const myDiagram =
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
    {
      layout: $(go.TreeLayout, { angle: 90, setsPortSpot: false, setsChildPortSpot: false })
    });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",
    $(go.Shape, { fill: "white" }),
    $(go.Panel, "Table",
      {
        margin: 0.5,
        defaultSeparatorPadding: new go.Margin(7, 9, 5, 9),
        defaultRowSeparatorStroke: "black",
        defaultColumnSeparatorStroke: "black"
      },
      $(go.RowColumnDefinition, { column: 0, background: "white", coversSeparators: true }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { row: 0, rowSpan: 2, column: 0, width: 100, textAlign: "center" },
        new go.Binding("text")),
      $(go.TextBlock, "Existing", { row: 0, column: 1 }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 1 },
        new go.Binding("text", "existing")),
      $(go.TextBlock, "Needs", { row: 0, column: 2 }),
      $(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 2 },
        new go.Binding("text", "needs"))
    )
  );

myDiagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    {
      routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
      fromSpot: new go.Spot(0.001, 1, 60, 0),
      toSpot: new go.Spot(0.001, 0, 60, 0)
    },
    $(go.Shape)
  );

myDiagram.model = new go.TreeModel(
[
  { key: 1, text: "CEO", existing: 1, needs: 1 },
  { key: 2, parent: 1, text: "IT Manager", existing: 1, needs: 2 },
  { key: 3, parent: 2, text: "React Developer", existing: 1, needs: 5 },
  { key: 4, parent: 3, text: "RDBMS Dev", existing: 2, needs: 3 },
  { key: 5, parent: 1, text: "Marketing Manager", existing: 1, needs: 1 },
  { key: 6, parent: 5, text: "Sales", existing: 2, needs: 5 },
]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:
[image]

Note that GoJS is a commercial library.

Comment: this is so awesome, it's works! but if any an open source library, it can be written below here too! Thank you!